# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - Asp.net Mvc DropDown Binding With Web Api

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to binding cascading dropdownlist with asp.net mvc and web api.

Web api works well. And my controller class returning values. I'm suspecting jquery has some error. I tested my controller with postman. I got some values. After selecting parent dropdown i got this error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```
public JsonResult GetirBolumler(int fakID)
    {
        List<Core.ViewModel.BolumViewModel> bolumler = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.myapiaress.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Danismanlik/ListeleBolum?FakulteID=" + fakID).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                bolumler = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Core.ViewModel.BolumViewModel>>().Result;
            }
        }

        return Json(new SelectList(bolumler, "ID", "Ad"));



    }
```

and jquery in view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //BÖLÜMLER DROP DOWN DOLDUR
        $("#ddlFakulteler").change(function () {
            alert('1');
            $("#ddlBolumler").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetirBolumler")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { fakID: $("#ddlFakulteler").val() },

                success: function (bolumler) {
                    $.each(bolumler, function (i, bolum) {
                        $("#ddlBolumler").append('<option value="' + bolum.ID + '">' + bolum.AD + '</option>');
                        alert('3');
                    });
                    alert('2');
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Bölüm getirme hatası.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
        //BÖLÜMLER DROP DOWN DOLDUR
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about to empty values.

Solved like this

I changed this line

```
data: { fakID: $("#ddlFakulteler").val() },
```

To

```
data: { fakID: fakulteID }, //fakID goes to controller
```

And put these lines

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlFakulteler");
var fakulteID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

After this line

```
 $("#ddlFakulteler").change(function () {
```